# Rails model's callback is not allways fired from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, callback, has-many, belongs-to

I've got a strange problem. For example i have only two models:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :shelf  
    after_update :specific_callback  
    private  
    def specific_callback  
        # some actions here  
    end  
end  

class Shelf < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
end
```

So the problem is that if i change exact book-shelf relation through book - for example:

```
book.shelf = shelf  
# or  
book.shelf_id = shelf.id
```

and then if i save book - its okay, so callback fires normally, but if i work with book through **shelf** and with its method **book_ids** there problems start, for example:

```
shelf.book_ids = [1,2,3]
```

here callbacks for books are only firing on newly added books, in other words if **book.shelf_id** changes from nil to some shelf.id - it's okay, and callback fires normally, but if **book.shelf_id** changes to nil from something - there is no firing of callback.
I see all queries in console when shelf_id changes for all books, but callbacks not firing for those who get nil for shelf_id.
Ive already tried to use after_update, after_save. Ive even tried to use observers, but the problem stills appears.

Comment: `Is called after Base.save on existing objects that have a record.` maybe it means that if book.shelf_id changes to nil so it doesn't know a record now and callback will not be firing?

Comment: If so, that means that i do not understand rails activerecord well, because i see sql query in console where book.shelf_id updates to nil, and i think that this event should 100% fire all book callbacks. if this isnt true i better find another way to solve my problem.